# Cannot find module in Electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I am currently working on Electron with Babylon. I found [this repo](https://github.com/boehm-s/electron-babylon-test) which I basically used as a boilerplate for my own project. 
Everything was working well until I tried to add [jquery.pep.js](http://pep.briangonzalez.org/) for other needs.
I keep on having this mistake :

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery.pep.js'

I installed both libraries with "npm i -S jquery" and "npm i -S jquery.pep.js". In order to make jquery works, I added this script in the head of my index.html

```
<script> delete window.module; </script>
```

and this line in the top of my main.js :

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Now, jquery is working fine but for some reasons, jquery.pep.js module still can't be found. I tried to use 'require' but I have the same error

**main.js**

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); 
var pep = require('jquery.pep.js');
```

**Project structure** 

css/
img/ 
js/ 
-- main.js 
node_modules/ 
index.html
index.js
package.json
renderer.js

Comment: We don't have enough info to help you. What we see is that the module is not found. We also need to see the exact file that tries to load the module and perhaps also the folder structure of your project. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok thanks, I just added some informations. As far as the problem doesn't concern WebGL, I only kept my main.js file and imported the librairies

Comment: And you confirm that by cd-ing to the `js` folder, running `node` and then printing `module.paths`, you have `'jquery.pep.js'` somewhere in the paths listed by this command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are requesting something and node is not able to find it. You can read this [dedicated article on requiring modules in node](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8), which explains it quite simply. Quoting:

> When we require a 'find-me' module, without specifying a path:
>
> `require('find-me');`
>
> Node will look for `find-me.js` in all the paths specified by
>   `module.paths` — in order.
>
> ```
> $ node
> > module.paths
> [ '/Users/samer/learn-node/repl/node_modules',
>   '/Users/samer/learn-node/node_modules',
>   '/Users/samer/node_modules',
>   '/Users/node_modules',
>   '/node_modules',
>   '/Users/samer/.node_modules',
>   '/Users/samer/.node_libraries',
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.7.1/lib/node' ]
> ```
>
> The paths list is basically a list of node_modules directories under
>   every directory from the current directory to the root directory. It
>   also includes a few legacy directories whose use is not recommended.
>
> If Node can’t find `find-me.js` in any of these paths, it will throw a
>   “cannot find module error.”
>
> ```
> ~/learn-node $ node
> > require('find-me')
> Error: Cannot find module 'find-me'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>     at repl:1:1
>     at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:23:33)
>     at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:336:29)
>     at bound (domain.js:280:14)
>     at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
>     at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:533:10)
> ```

Make sure you have your module installed somewhere in what node knows as `module.paths`, or reference the file by providing absolute path.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I just don't understand why jquery can be easily loaded and my other library need to use an absolute path because I added them into my project almost the same way.

Comment: Node doesn't care how you installed them, be it globally or not, as long as the module is in the module.paths as I specified. If you know it won't affect your environment, you can install your module globally (`npm install module -g`)

Comment: @Nagah Probably when you installed your module `npm i -S jquery.pep.js` at the command line, you were in some random directory, instead of having your terminal navigated to the root of your project. `npm install` without the global `-g` flag installs to the *current* directory, relative to where you run your command from