# Access Node module on Electron child process after compiling

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am making an App with electron and in the main process, i make an xml parser using child process with the following code:
xmlparser.js

```
const {parseString} = require('xml2js')
const moment = require('moment')
const testStrangeLayer = new RegExp(/^\de-\d$/)

const parseXML = function(str) {
    try {
        parseString(
            //parse function goes here
        )
    } catch(e) {
        process.exit(3)
    }
}

process.on('message',parseXML)
```

and it is consumed with this:
consumer.js

```
const fork = require('child_process').fork
const proc = fork('xmlparser.js')
let result
proc.on('message',function(m){
    result = m
    console.log('parse successful')
    proc.kill()
})
proc.on('exit',function(code,signal){
    if(code) {
        console.error('parsing error')
    } else {
        console.log(result)
    }
})
proc.send(data)
```

When i am on development stage, this works just fine. The problem comes after i compile the app. And here's the error i found:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'xml2js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:473:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\<Path to App Folder>\resources\other-scripts\app\xmlp
arser.js:1:178)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\<Path to App Folder>\resources\other-scripts\app\xmlp
arser.js:53:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:642:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
parsing error
(node:10888) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): #<Object>
(node:10888) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejection
s that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
module.js:545
    throw err;
    ^
```

I wonder what went wrong, i even already add 'child_process' to the project's dependency list. And my aim is to distribute this app without client installing nodejs on their machine.

Thanks for your helps

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075839/cannot-find-module-in-electron?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Thanks, but sorry that doesn't work. I mentioned earlier that it works on development but failed when it is bundled

Comment: Did you add the `xml2js` to your dependencies or your devDependencies?

Comment: I did, it's in the list of dependencies