# Require in electron.js / Uncaught Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an Electron application, and need a feature like `module.exports`. But it seems like it's not supported.

If I try,

**index.js**

```
const helper = require('./helper')

let importantVar = helper.getImportantVar
```

**helper.js**

```
function getImportantVar() {
    let foo = 'bar'
    return foo
}

module.exports = {
    getImportantVar: getImportantVar
}
```

I get,

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'helper'

Any idea how I can proceed with this, to get the same functionality.

*using electron: 6.0.12*

Comment: Are you sure that the path to `helper.js` is correct. If both scripts are in the same folder use `const helper = require(__dirname + '/helper')`, because `./helper` is a path considered relative to the folder from which you are calling the script.

Comment: thanks <3, so `require('./scripts/helper')` works hehe! was that what you ment with `__dirname` or is that something else?

Comment: Check whether your `helper.js` is in current directory??

Comment: @Subburaj `helper.js`and `index.js` are in the same dir!

Comment: @codtex if you post your comment as a proper answer I'll accept it! :D

Comment: @Strazan according to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18283508/5452965) answer if `helper.js` and `index.js` are in the same folder your code `require('./helper')` should work. I am not sure how paths resolve in electron. After all your problem seems to be a wrong path and I don't thing it is a good answer to say _"Fix your path"_ :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075839/cannot-find-module-in-electron)